# Excel Copy, Paste, Transpose below loop until

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am a total beginner at VBA and couldn't find or piece together the code to do what I want to do. It seems like it should be simple, I am just so unfamiliar with VBA right now I am having trouble.

> here is what I am trying to do in a loop until row 1 is empty

[image]

> Here is an image of what I have so far

[image]

I know i can delete the lines after 
"False, Transpose:=True"

I am not sure how to add the loop or the do until Row 1 is empty and to keep moving the transposed paste down the row.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of giving a picture of the code, can you kindly edit it in to your post, and format with the code tags, `{}`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This code:

[image]

Turns this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

Comment: I like the screenshots!

Answer (score 1):

Well actually you have two solutions :

```
 Range("A1:C5").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Range("A12").Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
 False, Transpose:=True
```

Or you can make it more flexible by doing

```
Sub transposeTable() 
Dim intLine, intCol, intLine2, intCol2 as Integer

    intLine = Sheets(SHEET_PAGE).range(strRange).Row 
'Ex : Sheets("Sheet1").range("firstTable")

    intCol = Sheets(SHEET_PAGE).range(strRange).Column
    intLine2 = Sheets(SHEET_PAGE).range(strRange2).Row
    intCol2 = Sheets(SHEET_PAGE).range(strRange2).Column

    While Sheets(SHEET_PAGE).Cells(intLine, intCol) <> ""
         ' Transpose code here, where the value at a(i,j) goes to a(j,i)       
        intLine = intLine + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your reason for using `Select` and `Selection` in your first method?  Why not just use `Range("A1:C5").Copy`  and `Range("A12").PasteSpecial ...(various arguments)...`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Just because it seems more organized in that way, so I can see clearly which range is being selected.

Comment: I suggest you read [How to avoid using select in excel vba macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros), especially the response of @SiddharthRout who provides the reasoning as to why this should be avoided, and others who show a better way to organize your code.